# differentiate gauge transformation

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory

Suppose $A_0$ a connection on principal bundle $P$, pick $\xi$ an elements in $\Omega^1(adP)$ and $e^{t\xi} \in \Omega^0(AdP)$ a one-parameter group generated by $\xi$.

（edited：Suppose $G$ the correspondent Lie group of $P$, $\Omega^0(AdP)$ means the $G-$ equivairant maps from $P$ to $G$(more explicitly, any $f \in \Omega^0(AdP)$ satisfied $f(pg^{-1})=gf(p)g^{-1}$ ) and $\Omega^0(adP)$ is the section of associated vector bundle(Whose correspondent vector space is $lie(G)$ and quotient the adjoint action), which also can be viewed as lie algebra of $\Omega^0(AdP)$）

My problem is, how to show that $\frac{d}{dt}(\exp^{t\xi}•A_0)=-\nabla_{A_0}\xi$? here $g•A_0$ denotes the gauge transformation given by $g\in Aut(P),\nabla_{A_0}$ the induced exterior covariant on $\Omega^1(adP)$.

Thanks you for your answer！

Comment: You should provide more context about the definitions you use. What type of connection to you speak of and how precisely are your gauge transformations defined?

Comment: @G.Blaickner Sorry I find there some mistakes in the initial problem and I've corrected it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes indeed more sense. However, they notation is still not clear to me. As you say, $e^{t\xi}\in\Omega^{0}(\mathrm{Ad}(P))$. The set $\Omega^{0}(\mathrm{Ad}(P))$ is just $\Gamma(\mathrm{Ad}(P))$, which is isomorphic to $\{f:P\to\mathfrak{g}\mid \forall p\in P,g\in G:f(pg)=\mathrm{Ad}_{g^{-1}}f(p)\}$. However, that is not quite the same as $\mathrm{Iso}(P)$. So, it is not clear to me how $e^{t\xi}\cdot A_{0}$ is defined. Is this problem from some textbook?

Comment: Or do you assume that $G=\mathrm{Gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$? Because than $G\subset\mathfrak{g}$ and we can identify $\Gamma(\mathrm{Ad}(P))$ with $C^{\infty}(P,G)^{G}\cong\mathrm{Iso}(P)$, where $C^{\infty}(P,G)^{G}=\{f:P\to G\mid\forall p\in P,g\in G:f(pg)=gf(p)g^{-1}\}$.

Comment: Also, the notation $\nabla_{A_{0}}\xi$ seems to be quite weird. $\nabla_{A_{0}}$ acts on sections $\Gamma(\mathrm{Ad}(P))$ and not on $1$-forms. Do you maybe mean the exterior covariant derivative induced by $\nabla_{A_{0}}$, i.e. $\mathrm{d}_{\nabla_{A_{0}}}$?

Comment: @G.Blaickner Suppose $G$ the correspondent Lie group of $P$, $\Omega^0(AdP)$ means the $G-$ equivairant maps from $P$ to $G$(more explicitly, any $f \in \Omega^0(AdP) satisfied f(pg^{-1})=gf(p)g^{-1}$ ), this definition can be founded in page 134 section 13.4 of Taubes book Differential Geometry.

Comment: @G.Blaickner here I use different notation $\Omega^1{adP}$ and $\Omega^0{AdP}$ the former means the lie algebra of the letter one.

Comment: @G.Blaickner This notation $\nabla_{A_0}$ means the exterior covariant. It's a typo, sorry.

Comment: @G.Blaickner This problem is exactly formula (2.1.20) page 37 Donaldson's book Geometry of four-manifolds(without proof).